# Finding the Laurent expansion for $F(z)=1/(z-1)^2(z+2)$

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to find the Laurent expansion for the function $F(z)=1/((z-1)^2(z+2))$ in different regions of the complex plane.

The first is $D(0,1)$ and I've calculated the expansion to be the sum from $n=0$ to infinity of $(1/18)(-z/2)^n + z^n/9 + (n+1)z^n/3$.

The second region is ${z: 1<|z|<2}$. My question is whether or not this region has a different Laurent expansion to the first one? And if so, what do I need to do differently to $D(0,1)$ to find the expansion.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, the Laurent expansion is different. For example, it has nonzero terms for $z^n$ with $n < 0$. What you need to do differently depends on what you did to find the first expansion.

Comment: for the first expansion, i split into partial fractions and then used the binomial theorem

Comment: so how would i change my method?

Comment: Good. Then the only difference is how you apply the binomial theorem/geometric series expansion. For $\dfrac{1}{z-1}$ for example, you used the expansion converging in $\lvert z\rvert < 1$, now you need a series converging in $\lvert z\rvert > 1$. For that, write it $\dfrac{1}{z}\cdot \dfrac{1}{1-\frac1z}$. Similar for the other terms and other annuli of convergence, write the partial fractions as $x\cdot \dfrac{1}{(1-y)^k}$ with $\lvert y\rvert < 1$ in the annulus.